# Using Google Analytics to determine how much time a visitor spends in each section of my site

Tags: google-analytics, analytics-api

I have a site with various pages, like:

```
/about/history
/about/team
/contact/email-us
/contact
```

I want to figure out how much time people are spending on the entire `/about` section, and how much on the `/contact` section.

If I run a query on the Google Analytics API and set the dimension to `ga:pagePathLevel1` and the metric to `ga:avgTimeOnPage`, I get results like this:

```
{ pagePathLevel1: /about, avgTimeOnPage: 28 },
{ pagePathLevel1: /contact, avgTimeOnPage: 10 }
```

This looks roughly like what I want, but I'm not sure how to intepret it:

- Is the value of `avgTimeOnPage` the average time spent by any user on
  **all** pages that match that path?
- Or is it the average time spent by any user on `any` single page that matches that path?

I'm looking for the average time spent across **all** pages matching that path, but the time estimates look shorter than I'd expect.

Comment: Is /about a page?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I've updated the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Also keep in mind that analytics sees "zero" as the time on page for the last page in a session.  Nothing is sent to analytics when a visitor leaves your site.  Because of this, your time on page is likely to appear much shorter than you expect for common exit pages.

Answer (score 1):

In your Google Analytics account -> Your Website account ->All Website Data.

In the left side bar under Behavior -> Site Content -> All Pages, you can see the time a visitor spends on individual pages (average that is).